# How to keep the delimiter in the next item in preg_split?

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I split a string by a set of characters as

```
$str = 'a-1 90 b55 0 -4 4 c9';
$array = preg_split('#(?<=[abc])#',$str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

it preserves the delimiter in the previous element as ([demo](https://ideone.com/7vF45z))

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => -1 90 b
    [2] => 55 0 -4 4 c
    [3] => 9
)
```

but I want to keep it in the next item as

```
Array
(
    [0] => a-1 90
    [1] => b55 0 -4 4
    [2] => c9
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lookahead instead of lookbehind:

```
$str = 'a-1 90 b55 0 -4 4 c9';
$array = preg_split('#(?=[abc])#',$str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($array);
```

Since you're not using any capture group in your regex, therefore there is no need to use `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag.

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/N1ifOg)